# Why do I get an extra empty window in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, window, toplevel

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *

OPTIONS = ["Available","Busy","Invisible","Away"]

now = Toplevel()
variable = StringVar(now)
variable.set(OPTIONS[0]) # default value
details = {"U_status":""}
def verify():
    global u_status
    details["U_status"]=variable.get()
    print ("value is:" + variable.get())
    now.destroy()
def status():
    w = OptionMenu(now, variable, *OPTIONS)
    w.pack()
    button = Button(now, text="OK", command=verify, relief='flat')
    button.pack()
if __name__=='__main__':
    status()
    mainloop()
```

While running the above code, along with the window (I wanted) another empty window appears. Can anyone figure out what is wrong in this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here `now = Toplevel()` should be replaced with `Tk()`, like:

```
now = Tk()
```

When you use `Toplevel()` a `Tk()` window is made in the background, if its not already made(your case), and that is the reason you are getting a blank new window. Actually that blank window is your main window.

`Toplevel()` is used to make child windows for the parent `Tk()` windows,ie, if you want sub windows within your main window(`now`), you will use `Toplevel()`. Because more than one `Tk()` in your code will cause some errors later on.

Comment: But, once I do this I will be facing errors in deleting a window using .destroy()

Comment: @CodeCarbonate `now.destroy()` will destroy the main window, in your case, just press the button and it should destroy the window.

Comment: Suppose I name a variable called now and set it the value of Tk(), if I want to delete only the main window and to keep other parts of the program running I use now.destroy(). But I get an error.

Comment: What other part of program do you mean? Destroying a `Tk()` will destroy the whole app.

Comment: Just like resetting the value of now to Tk() and displaying the same window with a different content after destroying now.

Comment: I would say to make a new window with `Toplevel()` and show the new contents there

Answer (score 0):

The blank window is actually the root window of your app that tkinter creates by default. You probably want to be explicit, and create a `tk.Tk()` root, and keep a reference to it.

New windows can be spawned and destroyed at leisure; your app will continue to exist as long as you keep the root active.

Maybe something like this:

```
import tkinter as tk


def verify():
    now = tk.Toplevel(root)
    details["U_status"] = variable.get()
    txt = f'value is: {details["U_status"]}'
    tk.Label(now, text=txt).pack()
    now.after(3000, now.destroy)
    
def status():
    tk.OptionMenu(root, variable, *OPTIONS).pack()
    tk.Button(root, text="OK", command=verify, relief='flat').pack()
    
    
if __name__=='__main__':
    
    OPTIONS = ["Available", "Busy", "Invisible", "Away"]
    
    root = tk.Tk()
    variable = tk.StringVar(root)
    variable.set(OPTIONS[0])
    details = {"U_status": ""}
    status()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: But, when I run the code you gave, an error arises stating
NameError: name 'mainloop' is not defined

Comment: Yes, it has to be `root.mainloop()`, sorry, my bad - I corrected it.